# Android NFC Intents are not starting my activity

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I am trying to write a simple application to interact with NFC tags, but I cant seem to get my phone to do anything but trigger the default NFC tag app. I really just want to be able to intercept any tag I scan, determine if it has some data on it, and take action accordingly.

Right now my manifest file looks like

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".NfcActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

However when scanning an NFC tag, I never see the activity start. Am I missing something here? I tried placing the intent filter inside a `BroadcastReceiver` and had no luck either...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You cannot have your app started by all NFC tags you scan. Android will determine what the most suitable app is based on how specific the intent filter is. However, if your app is running in the foreground, you can use [NFC foreground dispatch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) to catch all NFC intents.

In `onCreate()` add:

```
mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
  this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
```

In `onResume()` add:

```
mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
```

In `onPause()` add:

```
mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
```

In `onNewIntent` you can get at the NFC tag like this:

```
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
```

Comment: The idea of NFC is that it can do things such as automatically perform the appropriate action on your phone. Some examples: open a URL in your browser, check-in to Foursquare, automatically connect with a Wifi network. Android determines which app to forward the NFC intent to based on the apps' intent filters. The most specific filter "wins". If more than one match is found, an app chooser is presented to the user. There is one exception: NFC foreground dispatch, where the app running in the foreground can request to get all NFC intents of a specific type.

Comment: I guess I just don't get why this was the chosen functionality, unlike SMS where the intent is able to be picked up and rebroadcast by any number of receivers. It seems silly that you are limited to taking only one action on an interaction with NFC tech.

Comment: One difference is that an NFC intent is associated with a connected NFC device, for example an NFC tag. Only one activity can communicate with it at a time; an NFC tag does not support multiple simultaneous connections.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day, this worked in Android 11,12, and 13(Google Pixel  6a) too.

Answer (score 7):

The SDK docs show this as a basic example.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Note the `category` element in the example above. It is really necessary (although the name "DEFAULT" suggests otherwise).

Comment: can you show me who can I launch different activites based on different NFC tags ? tag1/prod/234  or tag3/buyme/3422 . If there is prod, I want to fire a ProductionInfo activity, but with buyme I would like to put in a list,

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting the tags to be defined in NDEF format. So your program will only be launched if the tags being read is in NDEF format.

You can try more generic intent filters like TAG_DISCOVERED or TECH_DISCOVERED.

Answer (score 0):

Android automatically choses the *most relevant application* to handle the scanned NFC tag. You need to be more specific in your `intent-filter`, i.e. only listen for TEXT-Tags, URL-Tags, or CONTACT-Tags. This can be done by further specifying the filter, using, your example,  `<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />` for TEXT-Tags. Otherwise, the default NFC-Tag app will be triggered.